# How to use ng-class according to the html content - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am printing each element in my array as an HTML paragraph using `ng-repeat`.

```
<p ng-repeat="item in queries track by $index">{{ item }}</p>
```

The result is:

```
------------ title 1 --------------
content 1
------------ title 2 --------------
content 2
------------ title 3 --------------
content 3
------------ title 4 --------------
content 4
```

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to custom style paragraphs (e.g `color:red;`).

Comment: you could set a color property on each query in your controller or directive and then just call `item.color`

Comment: I just realized that Alexsander Azizi's edit removed an important part of the original question - applying the class/style only when the item contains the word "title". That changes the answer significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you add ng-class attribute

```
<p  ng-repeat="item in queries track by $index" 
              ng-class={someCustomClass: item.title} >{{ item }}</p>
```

if the above doesnt work then this should

```
<p  ng-repeat="item in queries track by $index" 
            ng-class={someCustomClass: Boolean(item.title) } >{{ item }}</p>
```

If i am wrong the idea is to supply an object literal to ng-class, where the key is the class name and the value is the condition to apply the class

so `ng-class={ theClassNameToUse: TheCondition }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ng-class, you can use this syntax:

```
ng-class="{'class-name': item.indexOf('title') >= 0}"
```

Or, you can use ng-style like this:

```
ng-style="setColor(item)"
```

With the function:

```
$scope.setColor = function (item) {
    if (item.indexOf("title") >= 0) {
        return { color: red };
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @WonderGrub , your solution works nice for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do:

```
<p  ng-repeat="item in queries track by $index" 
    ng-attr-style="{{ item.indexOf('title') != -1 ? 'color: red' : '' }}">{{ item }}</p>
```

Comment: thak you so much @Gevorg Harutyunyan your solution works great  , (y)